# How can Flask/Python import config file that is one level up higher

Tags: python, flask, config

I'm writing a Flask web app and I ran into a small problem that really bothers me. This is my microblog.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from forms import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
...
```

And this is my project structure:

```
microblog\
  flask\
    <virtual environment files>
  app\
    static\
    templates\
    __init__.py
    microblog.py
    forms.py
  tmp\
  run.py
  config.py
```

My question is why does the config.py file has to be out of the app folder and is one level up? I can't really tell myself that it's "magic" so I have to find the answer but I've failed miserably so far.

My findings suggested that it has something to do with the import system (python import is really weird) but the thing is, my microblog.app.root_path is ... (/Users/myname/microblog/app) so there is no way it could have seen the config file. What's going on?

If you know the answer, please rescue my poor soul from this madness. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a Python file for your config, why not use a format more suitable for these kind of work.  One such candidate is JSON, and you could do something like this (as a variation on what the [Step 2 of the official tutorial suggests](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/setup/)):

```
import json

with open('../config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

app.config.update(config)
```

And instead of the `config.py` file you would have a `config.json` file (at the same location) that might look like

```
{
    "DEBUG": true,
    "SECRET_KEY": "development key"
}
```

Of course, you don't have to use `json`, there are other configuration file formats out there ready for you to use, but it's up to you to look up on how to use that.

Comment: Oh, I was following this tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world/page/0#comments                                                 and the author is using config.py. I agree that JSON would be better but I was just curious about why the config file was used in microblog.py even though it is one level up.

Comment: It probably expects you to copy that to somewhere else later so it can be imported from the script, I really don't know as I find the `config.py` pattern for storing configuration settings to be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on that Flask tutorial, `run.py` is what you're actually running when you start the app, and `run.py` is in the same directory as `config.py`. When you run `python` from the command line, the current directory is generally on your module path, so if you run `run.py` from that directory, then `config` is available on your path (as an absolute import)

I just glanced at the deployment part of the tutorial but it's possibly counting on the `microblog` directory being the working directory.

Comment: I agree with you. That seems to be the only way that makes sense. However, my `run.py` import `microblog.py`. And as you can see in `microblog.py`, I imported `LoginForm()` with `from forms import LoginForm()` and if the path is in the `microblog` folder, how come the import isn't `from app.forms import LoginForm()`